# Luggage type for short, frequent business trips

Tags: air-travel, luggage

I am going to have a lot of short (1-2 days/1 night) business trips. I will fly one or two segments in the morning and come back next evening on a symmetrical route. I am pondering what would be the best type of luggage to buy for this kind of use case. Luggage must be taken into cabin and be as lightweight as possible.

The options are:

1. Weekender 30-40 liters
2. Backpack 30-40 liters (has also to accommodate a laptop)
3. Troller (30 liters) + messenger (15 liters)

What would be the most practical one in this situation?

Comment: Some of this depends on what you need to carry. A backpack could be a good choice if you just need a t-shirt, toiletries, and laptop, while you might want a more suitable bag if you need to carry a folded suit or dress shirts.

Comment: I'm sorry but questions of the type "What is best?" are likely closed as *primarily opinion-based* in the absence of very clear criteria. You might want to ask instead what are the criteria/thoughts to take into account in making the choice between the options you list, that would be more on-topic imho. See also our help center on this [https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: It's a very answerable travel question.  Let's not be pedantic and unhelpful.  There are many experienced members who can offer considerations that aren't opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a road warrior myself, I try to carry as little as possible.

For shorter trips ~5 Days, I now prefer to take just a backpack in the 40L range.  Similar to this one: [Wander Pack](https://www.timbuk2.com/wander-pack/2580-3-4730.html?category=laptop-backpacks).  I really like having the separate shoe/dirties compartment.  Backpacks are also much lighter than rollers.

If you do go the backpack route, be sure to have one with **stowable straps in case you do want/need to check it**.  The airlines really, really don't like dangly things.

Paired with a tech vest such as the [AyeGear V26 Vest](https://smile.amazon.com/AyeGear-Vest-Pockets-Tablets-Black/dp/B00UVZLBEI/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1525890292&sr=8-4&keywords=travel%20tablet%20vest) and I'm all good.  Even for longer trips if I can do laundry.

For longer, multi-venue, special activity trips, I take a large rolling duffle which must be checked.  I did the overhead spinner thing for a long time and now find the backpack is easier to handle.

Comment: As the trips are in the range of 2 full days I tend on buying this one: https://www.ospreyeurope.com/shop/eu_en/transporter-40-2017 - it seems to be just right for hop-on, hop-off plane travel.

Comment: @DanielVoina Great choice!  Let me also say, compression cubes also help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you want easy access to (some of) your stuff while you're in the air, Choice 3 would allow you to store the messenger bag at your feet, under the seat in front of you. I travel this way, with all my can't-lose stuff, like medicines and computer, in the small bag.

If you want to carry all your luggage on board (to avoid the time sink of waiting for the luggage carousel upon arrival), make sure whatever bags you choose fit the airline's carryon size and weight limits. On the other hand, the convenience of checking a larger bag through for a two-segment flight may outweigh the quicker exit if you carry the larger bag with you in the cabin.

Finally, if you're not eager to wear a loaded backpack as you trek through the terminal and onto the street, choose a rollerbag.